# Ajax for incorporated in the same div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the page (`index.php`) that contain one link with `id="t1"` and one div `id="container"`.

```
<a id="t1" title="Users" href="utenti.php">Users</a>
<div id="container">
   <!--Where does the contained--> 
</div>
```

When I click the link I get a built-in external page (`utenti.php)`

This is code of Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#t1").click(function(){
            //$("#container").hide();
          $("#container").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){      
                   $("#container").show();
                   event.preventDefault();
                   });
            return false;
         });

});
```

and so far all is well, but if I click a link in the page that is included (utenti.php) the page is not incorporated in the same div but is opened in a direct manner.

I tried to put in the file .JS the code Ajax, to recognize the ID of the links transforming into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#t1").click(function(){


            //$("#container").hide();
          $("#container").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){      
                   $("#container").show();
                   event.preventDefault();
                   });
            return false;
         });

      $("#click").click(function(){
             //$("#container").hide();  
          $("#container").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){  
                $("#container").show();
                   event.preventDefault();
                });
            return false;
         });             


});
```

Where `#click` is `id` of the link contained in the page `Utenti.php`,but even so
I do not incorporate the page in the div.

I also tried to include directly the page with the script inside the page `utenti.php` but I recognize the first link (which is fine) but everyone else does!(not all other!)

If I understand correctly this system does not include actually the page as would the classic include of PHP.

He gives him also the values ​​already included in the index is more a kind of visualization,only that I haven't understand how to pass the value of the links contained in utenti.php inside the main page `index.php`.

Comment: i think u must move `e.preventDefault()` as the first statement in the click function

Answer (score 0):

If you want links on the page that is opened in the div to also be targeted to the div you can try a delegated click handler on the div itself.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#t1").click(openLinksInDiv);
    $("#container").on("click", "a", openLinksInDiv);

    function openLinksInDiv(event) {
        //$("#container").hide();
        $("#container").load($(this).attr("href"), function () {
            $("#container").show();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AN56C/

Or if you want all links on the page to open in that div, use:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", openLinksInDiv);
```

Noting that loading pages via Ajax won't work for any and all pages from external domains, but will work for pages from your own domain.

This whole thing seems to be the perfect case for an iframe rather than a div, in which case you could have links to external domains.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 $(document).on("click","#t1",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     $("#container").load(href);
    });
```